# discord.py Leveling System

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So during my time of developing Discord bots, I have always scared away from "leveling systems" or "leveling ranks" because it always seemed so complicated. Until today when I decided to finally start on this for a custom bot that I am making. I have no idea where to get started because I'm not really an expert when it comes to databases, json or even xp calculations. I've really only touched on json a couple times before.

I've tried to look at many examples on Github so that I could use them to start with my system but I couldn't get any working examples. I also looked at the [mee6_py_api](https://pypi.org/project/mee6-py-api/) as the server I'm working on a custom bot for, is currently using MEE6 so it would be ideal to export the current MEE6 data on the server then import it into my bot.

I know I'm supposed to link some code so here's something that I'm working on currently that I literally just copied and can't get to work

```py
import discord
from mee6_py_api import API
from discord.ext import commands
import json


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or(">"), intents=discord.Intents.all())

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    synced = await bot.tree.sync()
    print(f"Logged in as {bot.user} (ID: {bot.user.id})")
    print(f"Synced {len(synced)} commands.")


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if not message.author.bot:
        print('function load')
        with open('level.json','r') as f:
            users = json.load(f)
            print('file load')
        await update_data(users, message.author,message.guild)
        await add_experience(users, message.author, 4, message.guild)
        await level_up(users, message.author,message.channel, message.guild)

        with open('level.json','w') as f:
            json.dump(users, f)
    await bot.process_commands(message)




async def update_data(users, user,server):
    if not str(server.id) in users:
        users[str(server.id)] = {}
        if not str(user.id) in users[str(server.id)]:
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)] = {}
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['experience'] = 0
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['level'] = 1
    elif not str(user.id) in users[str(server.id)]:
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)] = {}
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['experience'] = 0
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['level'] = 1

async def add_experience(users, user, exp, server):
  users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['experience'] += exp

async def level_up(users, user, channel, server):
  experience = users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['experience']
  lvl_start = users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['level']
  lvl_end = int(experience ** (1/4))
  
  if lvl_start < lvl_end:
      await channel.send('{} has leveled up to Level {}'.format(user.mention, lvl_end))
      users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['level'] = lvl_end


@bot.command(aliases = ['rank','lvl'])
async def level(ctx,member: discord.Member = None):

    if not member:
        user = ctx.message.author
        with open('level.json','r') as f:
            users = json.load(f)
            lvl = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['level']
            exp = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['experience']

            embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Level {}'.format(lvl), description = f"{exp} XP " ,color = discord.Color.green())
            embed.set_author(name = ctx.author, icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url)
            await ctx.send(embed = embed)
    else:
      with open('level.json','r') as f:
          users = json.load(f)
      lvl = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(member.id)]['level']
      exp = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(member.id)]['experience']
      embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Level {}'.format(lvl), description = f"{exp} XP" ,color = discord.Color.green())
      embed.set_author(name = member, icon_url = member.avatar_url)

      await ctx.send(embed = embed)

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

I get this error whenever I type a message (so whenever `on_message` is called)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\amgha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 409, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "d:\Users\amgha\Downloads\leveling\mee6 api testing.py", line 21, in on_message
    users = json.load(f)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\amgha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\amgha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\amgha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\amgha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I would appreciate a solution to the error but would especially appreciate some sort of guide to answer the following questions so that I could be able to make this without copying some code:

How should I store all this data? (json, databse, etc.)

What's the best way to move the data from MEE6 to my bot?

thanks,

Comment: Opening the JSON file on every message is not ideal. Depending on the workload, you should select an appropriate database to store user data. If the workload is simple and you do not get much traffic, try looking into a simple single-file databases like [TinyDB](https://github.com/msiemens/tinydb). But, if you are comfortable with SQL, I would recommend you use SQLite since Python has built in support and it is reliable.

Comment: The server only has several hundred members but its growing so ill look into SQlite

Answer (score 1):

You very likely try to access a file that is empty, hence a char 0 error.

Check your file and make sure to first initialize it with some data.

---

You could add some saveguard before:
e.g. check for file existence, this is cheap but will not prevent the error - unless you delete the file beforehand

```
 if not os.path.exists('level.json'):
    with open('level.json','r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)
        print('file load')
```

Do a try...catch:

```
 with open('level.json','r') as f:
    try:
        users = json.load(f)
    except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError as e:
        print(e) # get informed which error happened
        print("Could not load file")
    else:
        print('file load')
```

---

PS: Doing a read-write on EVERY message is a bad way. Either accumulate updates in memory (some python dict with entries for each user) and update every 5 min or so. Use a (SQL)DB were updates are cheaper and also commit only after some time.
PS2: Note that your other questions are less suited for StackOverflow

Comment: im looking into SQL thanks for the response